# XNA c# Lerping -- Make 3d object follow another 3d object

Tags: c#, xna, dot-product, cross-product, lerp

I am making a game where an enemy AI follows a player 3d object. However, my enemy object spasms sometimes when following the player and freaks out. I think my issue may be somewhere in my dot product or my cross product math. Here is my code from my enemy class:

```
//here I get the direction vector in between where I am pointing and where my enemy is located at
       Vector3 midVector = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.Normalize(world.Forward), Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Subtract(p.position,this.position)), angleVelocity));
        //here I get the vector perpendicular to this middle vector and my forward vector
       Vector3 perp=Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(midVector, Vector3.Normalize(world.Forward)));

        //here I am looking at my quaternion and I am trying to rotate it about the axis (my perp vector) with an angle that I determine which is in between where I am facing and the midVector
       float angle=(float)Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(world.Forward,midVector));


           //Console.WriteLine(angle);



           Quaternion quaternion2 = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(perp, angle);


           quaternion = quaternion * quaternion2;

        //here I am simply scaling my world matrix, implementing my quaternion, and translating it to my position
       world = Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(quaternion) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);


       //here i move myself forward in the direciton that I am facing
       MoveForward(ref position, quaternion, velocity);


    }

    private void MoveForward(ref Vector3 position, Quaternion rotationQuat, float speed)
    {
        Vector3 addVector = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0, 0, -1), rotationQuat);
        position += addVector * speed;
    }
    public override void update()
    {

        base.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind rewriting your comments so that they don't include the words "I" or "my"? It seems like sometimes they refer to the player, sometimes they refer to the enemy, and sometimes they refer to you, the programmer.

Comment: What is the purpose of `midVector`? Why aren't you using the direction to the target?